# Can I center a jQuery UI dialog to a div?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I've got a main content div, and I'd like to centre the dialog to that div, rather than to the page. Any ideas? I know there's a position utility, but I can't work out how to use it with the dialog position options.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're correct, [`.position()`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/position/) is the way to go here, like this:

```
​$("#dialog").dialog()
            .parent() //remember .dialog() wraps the content in another <div>
            .position({ my: 'center', at: 'center', of: '#parent' });
  //or just .position({ of: '#parent' });
```

​
In the above `#parent` it the parent element selector, [you can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/mqLbu/).  You want the `my` and `at` properties to be `center` so they're centered op top of one another, then the `of` selector is the parent selector you want it centered in.

I specified all relevant options for illustration, but since `center` is the default for `my` and `at`, you can specify *just* the `of` like I have in the commented line above.

Comment: You make it look so easy! Thanks :)

Comment: The options are useful, as I've realised after experimentation that I actually needed `my: 'top', at: 'top'` (because if the dialog's too big, the top disappears out of the top of the browser).

Comment: @Skilldrick - I was wondering if they'd be at all helpful, I was thinking more for future users finding this, but excellent that they helped you as well :)