# JQuery dialog box not appearing in current screen center

Tags: php, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have a test php file which has 50 buttons in a table (just to make a big table). When the first button is clicked, I want a JQuery dialog box which has a html textbox to open via JQuery. For now, the code opens the textbox, but at the bottom of the screen. That is below the table. My objective is to open at the center of the current screen, ie, without being scrolled down by the user. Here's my code:

```
 <html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.js"></script>
       <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/jquery-ui.js">
**<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />**
</script>
        <script type="text/javascript" >
         $(document).ready(function(){
                  showClick();
        });

        function showClick(){ $('#comment0').click(function(ez) {
        $('#0').dialog('open');
        ez.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
    $('#0').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
        title: 'haha',
        height: 'auto',    
        draggable: true,
        position: 'center'
    }); }


    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
        ?><div id="0"><input type="text" ></div>
        <?php
        echo "<table>";
        for($i=0; $i<50; $i++) {?>
            <tr>
            <td><input type="button" class="comment0" value="Comment" id="comment0"></td>
            </tr>
            <!--div id="<?php echo $i; ?>" style="display :none"><input type="text" ></div-->       
            <?php
        } ?>
    ​
    <?php
        echo "</table></body></html>";
    ?>
```

Note: This is a quick dirty code, I was just testing the JQuery's behavior with big table size. What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks for any help!

**EDIT**: Turns out you have to import the JQuery CSS. Now the problem is, the dialog box opens at the center of the **table**. is there anyway for the dialog box to open at the center of the current screen? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the jquery UI stylesheet

`<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`

Comment: what? so easy! haha. this thing messed up my head for two days! Thank you very much!!

Comment: wait.. this now opens at the center of the table. is there anyway not to do that? thanks! I will edit my original post.

Comment: @javaCity dialog() has [position()] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3816250/can-i-centre-a-jquery-ui-dialog-to-a-div)

Comment: @nonnb yes, I am aware of that. Even though I do position: 'center' it goes to the center of the whole table. I want it to be at the center of the current screen.

Comment: I tried position: 'fixed' and 'absolute', none of them seem to work. it just centers to the table, no matter what I do.

Answer (score 2):

I finally figured out what was wrong with my program. In the HTML, I hadn't provided

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

After giving this, the dialog box was centered in the current screen!